# Java 8 lambda within a lambda can't modify variable from outer lambda

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

Suppose I have a `List<String>` and a `List<Transfomer>`.  I want to apply each transformer to each string in the list.

Using Java 8 lambdas, I can do this:

```
strings.stream().map(s -> {
    for(Transformer t : transformers) {
        s = t.apply(s);
    }
    return s;
}).forEach(System.out::println);
```

But I'd like to do something more like this, however it results in a compile time error:

```
strings.stream().map(s -> transformers.stream().forEach(t -> s = t.apply(s))).forEach(System.out::println);
```

I'm just starting to play with lambdas, so maybe I just don't have the syntax correctly.

Comment: It might help to include the text of the compiler error.

Comment: Error:(49, 60) java: local variables referenced from a lambda expression must be final or effectively final

Comment: This question is very good; however, I would suggest that it should be moved to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Is there a way I can move it?  Or does that require more authority than I have?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The best way to do this with streams is to use `reduce`:

```
// make a transformer that combines all of them as one
Transformer combinedTransformer =

    // the stream of transformers
    transformers.stream()

    // combine all the transformers into one
    .reduce(

        // apply each of the transformers in turn
        (t1, t2) -> x -> t2.apply(t1.apply(x)))

    );



// the stream of strings
strings.stream()

// transform each string with the combined transformer
.map(combinedTranformer::apply);
```

Of course, this assumes that `transformers` is non-empty; if there is a possibility that it is empty, than it is simple enough to use the two-argument overload of `reduce` instead, like so (this assumes `Tranformer` is a functional interface):

```
// make a transformer that combines all of them as one
Transformer combinedTransformer =

    // the stream of transformers
    transformers.stream()

    // combine all the transformers into one
    .reduce(

        // the no-op transformer
        x -> x,

        // apply each of the transformers in turn
        (t1, t2) -> x -> t2.apply(t1.apply(x)))

    );



// the stream of strings
strings.stream()

// transform each string with the combined transformer
.map(combinedTranformer::apply);
```

---

The reason you got a compiler error is that, as the error says, outside variables used in a lambda expression must be *effectively final*; that is, declaring them `final` (if they aren't already) must not change the meaning of the program, or change whether or not it compiles.  Using a mutable assignment in a lambda is therefore generally forbidden, and with good reason:  mutation screws up parallelization, and one of the major reasons lambdas were included in Java 8 was to allow easier parallel programming.

Generally speaking, whenever you want to "sum up" results in some way, `reduce` (in any of its three overloads) is your go-to method.  Learning how to use `map`, `filter`, `reduce`, and `flatMap` effectively is very important when working with `Stream`s.

Comment: Thanks, that's quite a bit to take in with my limited experience using lambdas.  The syntax is a little confusing, but I'll go through it until I understand it :)

Comment: +1, but I'd find it easier to read the code if the comments were shorter or on separate lines so that there wasn't horizontal scrolling.

Comment: @DavidConrad How does that look now?

Comment: It's definitely better without horizontal scrolling. Whether so many blank lines are better, I leave to your judgment.

Comment: If you use the predefined UnaryOperator instead of Transformer you can use UnaryOperator.identity() instead of x->x. It always returns the same object while x->x unnecessarily creates a new lambda object.

Answer (score 1):

Lambdas (just like local classes) cannot ever assign to captured local variables, whether from an outer lambda, or from an enclosing method. Captured local variables must be effectively final.