# Why lambda expression in java?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I understand with lambda expression(LE) we can save few lines of coding  like object creation for functional interface. Also LE will be more readable. But i am sure that this is not the main  reason this feature is provided for. I search it on google for `Why Lambda expression in java` and i found this interesting quote at this [article](http://www.nagarro.com/at/de/blog/post/26/Lambda-Expressions-in-Java-8-Why-and-How-to-Use-Them)

> Prior to Java 8, processing the elements of any collection could be
>   done by obtaining an iterator from the collection and then iterating
>   over the elements and then processing each element. If the requirement
>   is to process the elements in parallel, it would be done by the client
>   code. With the introduction of Stream API in Java 8, functions can be
>   passed to collection methods and now it is the responsibility of
>   collection to process the elements either in a sequential or parallel
>   manner. -

To me this looks like the advantage of streaming api not LE. Even if LE was not provided developer could have achieved the same 
with creation of anonymous Consumer class.  The only advantage here i can see in favour of LE is developer does not have to remember object of which
functional interface needs to be created. So it takes java towards functional programming where dev is saying apply this function and he does not care
about object(let jvm handle this).

Is this the main advantage of LE  or there is another one major than this ?

**Update :-**

I tried below simple program where i tried to measure the performance parallel processing with lambda expression. Found that it took 84 unit of time with parallel processing and only 4 unit for sequential. Is it because program is not big enough and also thread overhead may be playing its role here ? May be advantages can be visible in larger function ?

```
public class Java8Tester {

   final static String salutation = "Hello! ";

   public static void main(String args[]){
      List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();


      for(int i=0;i <100;i++){
      stringList.add("Hello1");
      stringList.add("Hello2");
      }

     long startTime  = System.currentTimeMillis();
       System.out.println(startTime);
      stringList.parallelStream().forEach((string) -> {System.out.println("content is " + string);
      });
      long stopTime  = System.currentTimeMillis();
      System.out.println(stopTime);
      System.out.println("time taken in parallel processing" + (stopTime - startTime)); // took 84 units of time


       startTime  = System.currentTimeMillis();
       System.out.println(startTime);

     for(String str : stringList ) {
         System.out.println("content is " + str);
     }

       stopTime  = System.currentTimeMillis();
      System.out.println(stopTime);
      System.out.println("time taken in sequential processing" + (stopTime - startTime)); // // took 4 units of time
   }


}
```

Comment: if downvoter can explain , whats wrong here, it will be helpful for me to improve ?

Comment: We use a backport of the Stream API with Java 7 and it’s not “a few lines” but several hundred lines for the real life usage. Why aren’t we all using assembly language? There isn’t anything we can do with high level languages we can’t do using assembly language…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general you're right: Stream API could exist without lambda functions, using anonymous classes. Though it would look really ugly and work somewhat less efficiently. As for time measurement, your results are completely irrelevant. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32328781/4856258) for details.

Comment: thanks. Regarding time measurement. i tried to iterate second time also (as you said ` Very first call to the Stream API in your program is always quite slow ...` in the link you mentioned)using parallel stream, it still takes 8 units of time which is  higher than legacy for loop. Parallel retrieval should be faster.Right ? May be method is not big enough to do the bench marking. Is it ?

Comment: @MSach, there are more problems in your benchmark, not only warm-up. One of them is the fact that `System.out.println` call is synchronized. When the only operation made in parallel stream is globally synchronized, it makes no sense to parallelize it. You just waste time on creating threads, splitting the input and synchronizing them back on single monitor.

Comment: agreed this is not right test for bench marking  as there are not enough operations under forEach(which i was guessing) . Also because of this advantages of parallel processing have been nullified by thread overhead etc . Thanks

Answer (score 6):

I don't think lambda expressions have one main purpose, rather lots of small added benefits, that together make a huge impact.

- Lambdas remove a lot of boilerplate code.
- They make code shorter and easier to read.
- Reduced need for anonymous inner classes.
- Allows more code reuse.

Any many more features.

One of my favourite advantages of lambdas is the ability to make default interfaces methods. Something I don't think I can live without now.

So lambdas don't have one specific reason for existing. They open the doors to a lot more functional programming, allow Java to evolve, and overall make coding even more fun.

Answer (score 0):

Lambda Expression comes as a great plus feature in java 8. It allows faster development and is based on functional programming.
There are different ways to use lambda expression in your code depending upon **the compiler is able to identify data types, return types, overloaded function uniquely** (smart compiling is also called *Type inference*). For the Lexical scoping, [Link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/architect-lambdas-part1-2080972.html) can be referred.
Following are the ways you can use lambda expression:

a. if you want to define a method declared inside a functional interface, 
say, the functional interface is given as an argument/parameter to a method called from main

```
    @FunctionalInterface
    interface FInterface{
     int callMeLambda(String temp);
    }

   class ConcreteClass{

     void funcUsesAnonymousOrLambda(FInterface fi){
      System.out.println("===Executing method arg instantiated with Lambda==="));
     }

     public static void main(){
      // calls a method having FInterface as an argument.
      funcUsesAnonymousOrLambda(new FInterface() {

      int callMeLambda(String temp){ //define callMeLambda(){} here..
      return 0;
    }
    });

    /***********Can be replaced by Lambda below*********/
    funcUsesAnonymousOrLambda( (x) -> {
     return 0; //(1)
    }

    }
```

> FInterface fi = (x) -> { return 0; };
>
> funcUsesAnonymousOrLambda(fi);

Above is explains a particular usage of lambda expression, Let us take the locs with which we can see various other usages  --

```
 funcUsesAnonymousOrLambda( (String x) {
     return 0;
     });
```

can be implemented using lambda expr in many ways
a.  without curly braces, if only one liner--

```
  funcUsesAnonymousOrLambda((String x) -> return 0);
```

b.  Without return statement above (compiler is very smart to identify return automatically)
funcUsesAnonymousOrLambda((String x) -> 0);

c.  Without specifying String type of arg

```
funcUsesAnonymousOrLambda((x) -> 0);
```

d.
With curly braces and new local field initialised

```
funcUsesAnonymousOrLambda( (String x) ->
{ //curly braces as we need more statements

String newVarString = " world";
Sysout("___" + x +  newVarString);

});
```

NOTE: the above local field can be there but if some field from outer scope (local variable of outer method) is accessed inside, it allows getting that field but not modifying that field.
ref
[Java 8 lambda within a lambda can't modify variable from outer lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23451579/java-8-lambda-within-a-lambda-cant-modify-variable-from-outer-lambda)

> Collections.sort(list, (o1, o2) -> {return o1.compareTo(o2);}

Lambda Expr is also useful while implementing Comparator interface(much like above example) while implementing compare method.  Python is preferred sometimes over java when fast development is the requirement but lambda gives a new curve to java.