# Passing and casting a Comparator as argument of method using Lambdas

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream, comparator

How can I create a method that would accept a comparator with wildcard as argument, and then capture the class and use the comparator ?

```
public List<String> myFilter(Comparator<?> comp, Object value, Class c){
   return myList.stream()
         .filter(s->
              comp.compare(c.cast(s), c.cast(value))>=0
          ).collect(toList());
  }
```

EDIT:
Ok, In fact, Andrew's answer is very interesting and works quite well :)
Yet,given the comments, what I really should want is: instead of trying to cast within the method, expect that the cast had already been done within the comparator

so this would give:

```
  public List<String> filter(Comparator<String> comp){
         return myList.filter(s->comp.compare(s, null)>=0).collect(toList());
   }
```

and when calling it, this should be something like

```
   List<String> myNewList= filter((String s1, String s2)->{
                  try{
                      int i=Integer.parseInt(s1);
                      return Integer.compare(i, myRealCompareValue);
                 }catch(Exception e){
                      e.printStackTrace();
                     return null;
                 });
```

It doesn't look very nice though....

Comment: What is the type of `myList` and how is it declared?

Comment: You can’t. Either, the comparator is correctly typed, or you can’t use it without an unchecked operation.

Comment: String. it is declared in the constructor of my class, that also accepts a List<String> as argument.

Comment: @Myoch why don't you use `Comparator<String>` then?

Comment: @talex because the list can contain numbers (and if so, all elements are numbers).

Comment: Basically, myList can be one line (split given a delimiter) of the result of a call to Files.readAllLines()

Comment: @Myoch `List<String>` can't contain numbers (in fact it can, but it will be major design flaw).

Comment: @Myoch `readAllLines` returns a `List<String>`. What you may be saying is that the string may contain a number - in that case you can do a `try { Integer.parse(s); //here it's an integer } catch (Exception e) { //here it's not }`.

Comment: so your `myList` is of type `List<String>` and you want to check whether comparing the strings with the given object (which must most probably be of type `String` too, as otherwise the cast wouldn't work out) is >= 0? did I miss something? did you omit a mapping from the type to `String`? What is the exact signature of your method? or do you really mean, that you put integers inside your `List<String>` (which is possible, but not advisable)?

Answer (score 1):

In fact, my question was a possible duplicate of [How do I define a method which takes a lambda as a parameter in Java 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13604703/how-do-i-define-a-method-which-takes-a-lambda-as-a-parameter-in-java-8)

and what I really wanted to do was

```
 public List<String> myFilter(MyComparator c){
        return myList
           .stream()
           .filter(c::compare)
           .collect(toList());
 }
```

with and interface MyComparator:

```
  public interface MyComparator{
        public boolean compare(String s);
  }
```

and then this could be called:

```
   List<String> myNewList=filter((String s)->s.compareTo(whateverString)>=0);
```

or even:

```
   List<String> myNewList=filter((String s)->{
           try{
               return Integer.compare(Integer.parseInt(s), 10)>=0;
           }catch(Exception e){
               return false;
           });
```