# Java 8: Pass object's method & its arguments as parameter

Tags: java, design-patterns, lambda, java-8

I have two classes `A` & `B` , like this:

```
class A {
    public Integer fetchMax() {
       // Make a network call & return result
    } 
}

class B {
    public Double fetchPercentile(Integer input) {
        // Make a network call & return result
    } 
}
```

Now I need to provide `retry` mechanism for both methods `fetchMax()` & `fetchPercentile(Integer)`. I want to provide this behaviour using a `helper` class, where the `retry` method which can take `instance` of (A or B), `method-name` and `method-arguments`. The retry would basically do  reattempts on the provided method of the object.

Something like this:

```
class Retry {
     public static R retry(T obj, Function<T, R> method,  Object... arguments) {
           // Retry logic
           while(/* retry condition */)
           {
                obj.method(arguments);
           }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just take a [`Callable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) as argument:

```
public static <R> R retry(Callable<R> action) {
    // Retry logic
    while(/* retry condition */) {
        action.call();
    }
}
```

And call it this way:

```
Retry.retry(() -> a.fetchMax());
Retry.retry(() -> b.fetchPercentile(200));
```

You might want to use, or get inspiration from [guava-retrying](https://github.com/rholder/guava-retrying), a small extension to Google's [Guava library](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Guava) to allow for the creation of configurable retrying strategies (disclaimer: I'm the original author).

Comment: Throughout the question I couldn't just see what was required there and if it related to using Callable, yet after reading this I think this could be what should be used instead by OP.

Comment: Yep, this is how you do it in pre java 8 as well. It should still work. A lambda expression can probably be used as well together with an interface, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13604703/how-do-i-define-a-method-which-takes-a-lambda-as-a-parameter-in-java-8